# Is it possible not collect marked test?

Tags: python, pytest

Currently, it is possible to **mark** tests and then run them (or not run them) using `-m` argument. However, all tests are still collected first and only then are **deselected**

In the below example all 8 are still collected, and then 4 are run and 4 are deselected.

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.2 -- C:\Python27\python.exe
collecting ... collected 8 items

test_0001_login_logout.py:24: TestLoginLogout.test_login_page_ui PASSED
test_0001_login_logout.py:36: TestLoginLogout.test_login PASSED
test_0001_login_logout.py:45: TestLoginLogout.test_default_admin_has_users_folder_page_loaded_by_default PASSED
test_0001_login_logout.py:49: TestLoginLogout.test_logout PASSED

==================== 4 tests deselected by "-m 'undertest'" ====================
================== 4 passed, 4 deselected in 1199.28 seconds ===================
```

QUESTION: Is it possible to **not collect** marked/unmarked tests at all?

The problems are:

1) I'm using some test when the database already has some items in it (like my *device*) and the code it have:

```
@pytest.mark.device
class Test1_Device_UI_UnSelected(SetupUser):

    #get device from the database
    device = Devices.get_device('t400-alex-win7')

    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope = "class", autouse = True)
    def setup(self):
    ...
```

I run the test explicitly excluding and *device* tests: `py.test -m "not device"` however, during collection I get the errors, because `device = Devices.get_device('t400-alex-win7')` is still being executed.

2) Some of the tests are marked `time_demanding` because there are around 400 generated tests. To generate those tests is also takes time. I exclude those tests from the *general* tests, however they are generated and collected and then deselected <- just a wait of time.

I know there is a solution for (1) problem - to use pytest.fixtures and pass them to the tests, however I really like *autocompletion* that PyDev provides.

`timedemanding` class is:

```
import pytest
#... other imports


def admin_rights_combinations(admin, containing = ["right"]):
    '''
    Generate all possible combinations of admin rights settings depending
    on "containing" restriction
    '''
    rights = [right for right in admin.__dict__.iterkeys() if any(psbl_match in right for psbl_match in containing)]
    total_list = []
    l = []
    for right in rights: #@UnusedVariable
        l.append([True, False])
    for st_of_values in itertools.product(*l):
        total_list.append(dict(zip(rights, st_of_values)))
    return total_list

@pytest.mark.timedemanding
class Test1_Admin_Rights_Access(SetupUser):

    user = UserFactory.get_user("Admin Rights Test")
    user.password = "RightsTest"
    folder = GroupFolderFactory.get_folder("Folders->Admin Rights Test Folder")
    group = GroupFolderFactory.get_group("Folders->Admin Rights Test Group")
    admin = UserFactory.get_admin("Admin Rights Test")

    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope = "class", autouse = True)
    def setup(self):
        ...

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("settings", admin_rights_combinations(admin, containing=['right_read', 
                                                                                      'right_manage_folders',
                                                                                      'right_manage_groups']))  
    def test_admin_rights_menus(self, base_url,settings):
        '''
        test combination of admin rights and pages that are displayed with 
        this rights. Also verify that menu's that are available can be opened 
        '''
```

As you can see, by the time pytest hits `@pytest.mark.parametrize` it should be already aware that it's in Class with `@pytest.mark.timedemanding`. However, collection still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not `py.test`, but the fact that the class code is executed when the file is imported, so you get the error **before** the decorator is even called.

The only way(without modifying the logic of the code) to avoid this is to completely ignore the whole file.

Anyway, I do not understand why you set the `device` class attribute there. Use the class-level `setup`! If you put that code in the setup your problem should be solved, because, since the test is not run, the setup is not called either and you do not get the error.

The same goes for the `time_demanding` tests.  Set them up in the class level setup, so that `py.test` does the class creation does not take so much time(even though, without a sample code, I can't say much about this).

If you want to keep things like this, and have PyDev autocompletion, then, as I said, just ignore the whole file with some regex(and eventually you'll have to split up the tests).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about the class import - it makes sense, so I changed to query `device`'s database info only when its attribute is requested for the first time(not during `init`). Also I've updated the `pytest.mark.timedemanding` case - it's still unclear why all the cases are generated only to be deselected.

Answer (score 0):

Deselecting tests only after collection is complete happens for two reasons:

- to always get a correct number of overall tests
- collection hooks might dynamically add or remove marks

Regarding auto-completion, i believe putting heavy setup into fixtures is more important.  I am not sure if Pydev could learn to still auto-complete.  You must have this issue also for regular
python functions which take in an argument where Pydev cannot really know what type it is.  FWIW i am living well with the dumb vim-completion which simply looks through all strings/names in all the buffers and completes on that.  It gives more false positives but no false negatives.

Comment: Holger, thanks for you answer. I was going through the hooks and was wondering if `pytest_pycollect_makeitem(collector, name, obj)` can make the change. Am I at the right direction? I'm refering to the (2)-nd case (`timedemaninding`)

Comment: it's not impossible to deselect tests early during collection.  Probably we would need to introduce an ini-option like "deselect-early" even though the dynamic modification of markers during collection is probably used rarely.  If you open an issue, i'll think about that if i get to it.